# OSX Yosemite LoginWindow agent not persisting into login

Tags: osx-yosemite, launch-agent

In Mavericks and earlier, LaunchAgent plist with LimitLoadToSessionType set to LoginWindow would always run the agent in the LoginWindow and persist it into the log in account session. 
Now in Yosemite, if you've specified LoginWindow as the only session type in the plist, the agent runs and only runs during the LoginWindow.

How can I persist the LoginWindow agent after login in OSX Yosemite?

Fixes I tried:

-Added Aqua in addition to LoginWindow but this is not feasible as I  cannot have the agent be stopped and launched again.

-tweaking other keys such as the KeepAlive, etc, but nothing helps. It's as if Apple thought "oh persisting LoginWindow only agents outside LoginWindow is a bug, lets fix it!".

Any help here would be appreciated and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is not what I understood the behavior to be.  If you wanted it to run when logged out and logged in you need to include LoginWindow and Aqua in the array.  However, you should be aware that it will kill the executable and relaunch at login.  This is how I remember it behaving on 10.9.  I have heard that 10.10 has a complete rewrite of launchd, and that it no longer executes multiple launchd processes for each user but only has one and uses xpc (cross process communication).

See this link: http://docs.macsysadmin.se/2014/pdf/Launchd_-_At_your_service.pdf

Comment: My launch agent only has LoginWindow specified in the array, and in all OSX versions prior to Yosemite, the launch agent persists from the LoginWindow into the user session, and there is no relaunch upon login. However you pointed out that Apple did a complete rewrite for 10.10 so that may be the cause of this sudden change of behaviour. Still no solution but thanks for the post.